# JList displaying String[] text cut off

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to populate a `JList` with items from an `ArrayList<String[]>`.  Each `String[]` is of the form ["I","am","an","example"] and there's nothing I can do about the input form - its from a third party.  What I'd like is simply a `JList` with each `String[]` expanded out on a different line.  When I use the following code, though, the first few characters are cut off the left side of the `JList` - its cutting off mid character so its an issue with pixels not characters.

The class below is set as the content pane on a `JFrame` elsewhere in the program, I didn't think it was necessary to copy that over here but if it would be useful then I can trim it down and put it up for viewing.

```
public class BookScreen extends JPanel{
ListSelectionModel lsm;
ArrayList <String> atList;
JList atBox;
MainForm mf;

public BookScreen (MainForm mf){
    //I'm aware this bit is clunky, it was a quick and dirty to test it displays 
    //properly before I cleaned it up
    ArrayList<String[]> books= mf.getWorld().getBooks();
    atList=new ArrayList();
    for (String[] s:books){
        atList.add(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
    //end clunky
    atBox = new JList(atList.toArray());
    lsm = atBox.getSelectionModel();
    lsm.addListSelectionListener(new BookScreen.AtListSelectionHandler());
    atBox.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    atBox.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    atBox.setLocation(0, 0);
    atBox.setVisible(true);
    this.add(atBox);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
class AtListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
    }
}
}
```

Screenshot of problem:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What if you add the list in JScrollPane? this.add(new JScrollPane(atBox))?

Comment: What are you adding the BookScreen into?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Stansilav - Hmmm, good idea.  @Joni - content pane of a `JFrame` - I'll trim it down and throw it up.  @Andrew Thompson - as above, I'll adjust and add the `JFrame` it goes with.

Comment: Ha.  Can't work how out to get a SSCE working and loathe to ask a new question about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set a layout manager on the panel, which means that the default `FlowLayout` will be used. If there's only one component this layout places it centered on the container; if the component is wider than the container its edges are trimmed.

To solve the problem simply set a different layout manager, for example `BorderLayout`:

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(atBox);
```

More information: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing: Using layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).